# Have I committed unintentional riddah (apostasy) by noticing that religions use the promise of heaven as a psychological mirage?

Tags: other-religions, apostasy

Recently, it occurred to me that almost every religion will promise its followers heaven. I came under the impression that religion may be a psychological shroud that covers the eyes of humans, but could not come to a conclusion of what happens after death.

For some reason, I am compelled to believe in Islam. I feel that it is more than a psychological mirage, and after searching into myself, I still feel compelled to follow Islam. I have never worshipped any other god or being other than Allah, this was merely a soul searching quest.

I am sure I have not committed shirk, but I am concerned if this sway in belief has caused me to become a murtad (an apostate).

Have I unknowingly committed riddah, even though I did not intend to?

Comment: Take it easy man! So long as you are your quest for knowledge on evidences of Allah, you're doing what Allah already urges us do in the Quran. To think, reflect and reason and find proof. There's no blind faith in Islam!

Comment: @Alif, I assume this is the thought of the Satan that.. then dont allow him to... I suggest u to read the sites below which could be beneficial for you: http://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa9301 _______

http://www.islamquest.net/ar/archive/question/fa8691

Comment: I recommend you to put a specific time for yourself to read the mentioned sites which could be beneficial for you. read the following site as well : http://www.islamquest.net/en/archive/question/fa12069

Answer (score 1):

so is this your question?

> have I unknowingly committed Shirik or Murtad even though I did not
>   intend to, and could the scholars please give me some guidance to
>   reinforce my Aqidah please? Thank you very much, assalamualaikum.

Shirik means you believe and worship other god , pray to the other thing than Allah Subhanahuwata'ala , and not believing that muhammad is messenger of our god, Allah Subhanahuwata'ala . this is our syahadat isnt it?

so as long as you have a faith to Allah Subhanahuwata'ala and pray to him and do what Allah Subhanahuwata'ala  told in our holy bible Al-Quran , you will be guided to Islam, and wont be Syirik, real islam, and it will make your faith stronger, 
there are so many miracles in al-quran that makes your faith stronger.

if you want to know who is the persons who get the miracle of quran  i'll give you 5

1st
Maurice Bucaill
2nd 
Jacques Yves Costeau
3rd
Demitri Bolykov

you can google about them, and they are islam because they read a quran and taste it miracles

so in conclusion if u want to make your faith stronger, read quran, know the tafsir and think about it, and always remember , Quran will never wrong, but sometimes the human who read it.

i hope your faith getting stronger and stronger brother.